# MATLAB code for Hamacher sum

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

The hamacher sum is :
[image]

I wrote the following MATLAB code for the above function

```
function f=hamachersum(x,y)
f = zeros(numel(x),1);
for j=1:numel(x)
    if x(j)==1 && y(j)==1
        f(j,1)=1;
    else 
        f(j,1)=(x(j)+y(j)-2*(x(j)*y(j)))/(1-(x(j)*y(j)));
    end
end
end
```

Then I want to test `t3=hamachersum(t1,t2)`
My input values `t1, t2` are

> > t1

t1 =

```
1.0000
     0
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
0.8167
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
0.4667
   NaN
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
   NaN
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
0.0250
1.0000
```

> > t2

t2 =

```
1.0000
0.5524
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
     0
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
   NaN
0.6032
1.0000
1.0000
   NaN
0.9973
0.7260
```

The result is

```
t3 =

    1.2000
    0.5524
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    0.8167
    2.0000
    2.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    0.6667
    1.0000
    1.0769
       NaN
       NaN
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    0.9973
    1.0000
```

Why do I get values **above 1**. As this is a fuzzy operator it can't have values above 1.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Setting `t1=[0:0.01:1]';` `t2=t1`, `t3=hamachersum(t1,t2)` results in values between 0 and 1, as does it when you use `t2=flipud(t1)`. I can't seem to find a fault in this code, running it on R2012a

Comment: You are not displaying a truthful `t3`. Plugging in the first elements `t1(1) == 1` and `t2(1) == 1` clearly yields `1`, not `1.2`. Please display the real answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  This is the output I get when run on R2014a

Comment: @Adriaan I ran it on R2014a. I don't know what is wrong but this is the output I get

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce your problem. I am unable to reproduce it!

Comment: @Daniel If I use `k1=[1,0,1,1,1];
>> k2=[1,0.5524,1,1,1];
>> k3=hamachersum(k1,k2)

k3 =

    1.0000
    0.5524
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000`  Here it works correctly. But for some reason for the above `t1 `and `t2` it produces values above 1, which I can't understand

Comment: @sam_rox: As the inputs "1" and "1" produce different outputs, I assume the values are not really "1" but rather close to "1". With the image it is impossible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Daniel  They are "1" . I included the MATLAB values for `t1` and `t2`

Comment: @sam_rox I just ran your code with those values, my output is different. Are you sure you are not overwritting t3 somewhere? I get: `t3 =

    1.0000
    0.5524
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    0.8167
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
       NaN
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
       NaN
    0.9973
    1.0000`

Comment: I would suggest changing `if x(j)==1 && y(j)==1` to `if x(j)>=1 && y(j)>=1`

Comment: @AnderBiguri  I entered values of t1 and t2 to new variables as `a1,a2` and used `a3=hamachersum(a1,a2)`. Then also I get the output as `t3` .  I changed as `if x(j)>=1 && y(j)>=1` . Still I get  `1.2` as the first value.

Comment: @sam_rox sorry, but It just makes no sense. Probably you have some other variables called t1 or t2, or you have some t1.m or t3.m or something like that. If you close Matlab, create a new directory, and there paste your function and execute it with the values you given us, you get the output I said, not the one you said, thus the Question here makes no sense and should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I am probably answering this against my better judgement.

**Caveat**: I am not familiar with the Hamacher sum so my approach to answering this is strictly based on the equation in your question.

---

> Is there something wrong in my code?

Your code produces `1.0` when I run it on MATLAB R2014a for inputs of `1.0` and `1.0`, I'm presuming that is correct as you have an explicit condition for it. I cant produce the results you are are seeing in your question.

However, I felt compelled to provide a more efficient implementation of the equation

```
function h = hamachersum(mu_a, mu_b)
    h = (mu_a + mu_b - (2 .* mu_a .* mu_b)) ./ (1 - mu_a .* mu_b);
    % h(isnan(h)) = 1.0; % Included this line to show you how to remove NaN
end
```

**Note**: I've included `% h(isnan(h)) = 1.0;` to show you how to handle cases when `mu_a` and `mu_b` are both `1.0` as you have explicitly handled this in your question (rather poorly might I add).

---

Comparing floating point numbers is not reliable even in MATLAB and could be part of the reason why you are receiving the results you are. A better way to check what the value of a floating point number is would be to use

```
if (x - 1.0 > 1e-15)
    fprintf(1, "x == 1.0");
else
    fprintf(1, "x ~= 1.0");
end
```

If `x` is equal to `1.0` down to machine precision this expression will be `true` otherwise it will be `false`.